# jQuery getJSON return data

Tags: jquery, getjson

I want return data from the jQuery getJSON method out of a function.

```
console.log(loadJson());
```

I think the failure is that I used a function in a function and my return is in the inner function. I have tried several opportunities and I can't find the correct solutions.

The result is always "undefined".

This is my simple code:

```
function loadJson(){
  $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) { 
    return data;
   });
}

console.log(loadJson());
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`getJSON` function from jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) is asynchronous. It has no return value until data is returned by the server.

Solution would be to use callbacks to handle asynchronous results or Promises with async or await.

Using callback:

```js
function loadJson(callback) {
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) { 
        callback(data);
    });
}

loadJson(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Hope this helps you.